# Call Library Function Node Error 1097

Tags: labview

I'm pretty new to labview and I'm trying to use a Call Library Function Node to use a function from my library.

The function has the following prototype:

```
int function_name(int arg1, void* arg2, int* arg3, my_enum* arg4);
```

My call function nodes has 5 parameters, the return and the ones of the function that i have set in this way:

- arg1, is a numeric I32;
- arg2, is an array of U8 passed by value;
- arg3, is a numeric I32 passed as a Pointer;
- arg4, is a numeric I16 passed as a pointer;

My setup doesn't work, and i get an error 1097.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is with arg2, which is a pointer to a memory location in which the function will leave some data.  How can I make it work?

I'm using LabView 2017, notice that arg2 and arg4 gets uploaded correctly.

Comment: Can we see your code? What version of LabVIEW are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't upload the code, but in the end it just copies some data to the buffer pointed by arg2, arg3 is the size in byte of the data copied and arg4 is the terminator of the data. The versione that i'm using is Labview 2017 and arg3, arg4 get updated correctly every time.

Comment: What is the bit-ness of LabVIEW and your DLL? Also, would you clarify and/or confirm the C types that are required by the function and the LV types that are wired to the CLN? For example: _arg1 is `int` in the C function and I wire an `i32` to the CLN's terminal._